# Getting more than expected with siblings().length

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
<div id="myDiv">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

When I execute this jquery code

```
var count = $('#myDiv table tbody tr').siblings().length;
```

I am expecting to get 8 as the value of count, instead I am getting 45. There is more html on the page than the area I have shown, and each of the above  elements hold various amounts of data. What am I missing?

Comment: It must be something else in your code. That will work fine otherwise. See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/HJXZC/. However, you can try getting rid of `.siblings()` and just using `length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var count = $('#myDiv table tbody tr').length;
```

or

```
var count = $('#myDiv tr').length;
```

Comment: I had that at first and that returns 47 for count. I added the siblings hoping to limit results.

Comment: Have you only one id="myDiv on your page?

Comment: I do only have one div with that Id. I attached a class to my table and took the value of that and it works. There was something I was missing with original code. Thanks for help.